# Usage of sed(stream editor)

Tags: sed, latex, markdown

I have a file containing text

```
**This is bold text** 
*This is italicized text*
```

I wish to convert the above into

```
  \textbf{This is bold text}
  \emph{This is italicized text}
```

using stream editor(sed). Kindly guide me on this matter.

I have used this code

```
sed -i 's/\*\*\(.*\)\*\*/\\textbf{\1}/g' SampleCode
```

and it works like a charm

Thanks from [Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/pandoc-discuss/qpvXJqFJOqk)

Comment: Do the texts ever span more than a single line?

Comment: Let's break this down into smaller chunks. What text do you wish to find, and what do you want to convert it to? Looks like you wish to find the first instance of two asterisks and replace it with ' \textbf{' - find the second instance of two asterisks and replace it with '}' - find the first instance of one asterisk and replace it with '\emph{' - find the second instance of one asterisk and replace it with '}' . Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are trying to invent new [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/).
Instead:

1. Install Pandoc:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install pandoc
   ```
2. Create input file:

   ```
   $ cat << EOF > file.md
   **This is bold text** 
   *This is italicized text*
   EOF
   ```
3. Run conversion from Markdown to LaTeX:

   ```
   pandoc file.md -o file.tex
   ```
4. Enjoy the result:

   ```
   $ cat file.tex 
   \textbf{This is bold text} \emph{This is italicized text}
   ```

Comment: I wish to understand how it works.

Comment: @pasmon As it is tradition, the full source code is available [online](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc) – you’re welcome to dive in.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple answer:

```
echo '**This is bold text**' | sed -r 's/\*\*(.+)\*\*/\\textbf{\1}/'
echo '*This is italicized text*' | sed -r 's/\*(.+)\*/\\emph{\1}/'
```

Most important thing is to understand regular expressions. There are several online regex testers where you can experiment with regex.

Here is a very good explanation of sed.
https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: I wish to use these commands used in a script file(.sh) to work on a global scale in a document . How to convert the commands listed above for that purpose?

Comment: fails for `**This** is bold **text**` – oh, and what about `**mixed *italicized* and bold**`, and multiline blocks? there are so many things to consider here, a tool like `pandoc` is the only sane solution IMO.